# Output console in RichTextBox c# WindowsForm

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make console output in RichTextBox. Here is my code:

```
public void Run()
{
    Process myProcess = new Process();
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"start.bat";
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcess.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
    myProcess.Start();
    myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

public void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   this.Invoke(new Action(() => 
   richTextBoxConsole.Text += (e.Data + Environment.NewLine)));
}
```

But only the first line of the console is displayed in the RichTextBox. It is necessary to display all lines in real-time. Where is the mistake?

Comment: are you sure there is more than one line output? try stepping through your code or printing to the debug window.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the console out to a new TextBoxStreamWriter. Should do the trick.

```
public class TextBoxStreamWriter : TextWriter
{
    private readonly RichTextBox richTextBox;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TextBoxStreamWriter"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="richTextBox">The richTextBox.</param>
    public TextBoxStreamWriter(RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        this.richTextBox = richTextBox;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes a character to the text stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The character to write to the text stream.</param>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ObjectDisposedException">The <see cref="T:System.IO.TextWriter"/> is closed. </exception>
    ///   
    /// <exception cref="T:System.IO.IOException">An I/O error occurs. </exception>
    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        if (this.richTextBox.Parent.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Action<char> action = Write;
            this.richTextBox.Parent.Invoke(action, value);
        }
        else
        {
            base.Write(value);
            this.richTextBox.AppendText(value.ToString());
            this.richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes out a formatted string, using the same semantics as 
    /// <see cref="M:System.String.Format(System.String,System.Object)"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="format">The formatting string.</param>
    /// <param name="arg0">An object to write into the formatted string.
    /// </param>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">
    ///   <paramref name="format"/> is null. </exception>
    ///   
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ObjectDisposedException">The 
    /// <see cref="T:System.IO.TextWriter"/> is closed. </exception>
    ///   
    /// <exception cref="T:System.IO.IOException">An I/O error occurs. 
    /// </exception>
    ///   
    /// <exception cref="T:System.FormatException">The format specification
    /// in format is invalid.-or- The number indicating an argument to be
    /// formatted is less than zero, or larger than or equal to the number
    /// of provided objects to be formatted. </exception>
    public override void Write(string format, object arg0)
    {
        if (this.richTextBox.Parent.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Action<string, object> action = Write;
            this.richTextBox.Parent.Invoke(action, format, arg0);
        }
        else
        {
            base.Write(format, arg0);
            this.richTextBox.AppendText(string.Format(format, arg0));
            this.richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When overridden in a derived class, returns the <see cref="T:System.Text.Encoding"/> in which the richTextBox is written.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The Encoding in which the richTextBox is written.</returns>
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```